# gatsby-remark-prismjs is not working on html

Tags: graphql, gatsby

gatsby-remark-prismjs is not working on my settings.

I'm trying to highlighting codes like javascript and swift.

My blog contents fetched from wordpress.com

[image]

Here is my gatsby.config.js

```
,
      {
        resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
        options: {
          plugins: [
            {
              resolve: `gatsby-remark-prismjs`,
              options: {
                // Class prefix for <pre> tags containing syntax highlighting;
                // defaults to 'language-' (eg <pre class="language-js">).
                // If your site loads Prism into the browser at runtime,
                // (eg for use with libraries like react-live),
                // you may use this to prevent Prism from re-processing syntax.
                // This is an uncommon use-case though;
                // If you're unsure, it's best to use the default value.
                classPrefix: "language-",
                // This is used to allow setting a language for inline code
                // (i.e. single backticks) by creating a separator.
                // This separator is a string and will do no white-space
                // stripping.
                // A suggested value for English speakers is the non-ascii
                // character '›'.
                inlineCodeMarker: null,
                // This lets you set up language aliases.  For example,
                // setting this to '{ sh: "bash" }' will let you use
                // the language "sh" which will highlight using the
                // bash highlighter.
                aliases: {},
                // This toggles the display of line numbers alongside the code.
                // To use it, add the following line in src/layouts/index.js
                // right after importing the prism color scheme:
                //  `require("prismjs/plugins/line-numbers/prism-line-numbers.css");`
                // Defaults to false.
                showLineNumbers: false,
                // If setting this to true, the parser won't handle and highlight inline
                // code used in markdown i.e. single backtick code like `this`.
                noInlineHighlight: false,
              },
            },
            ],
          },
      },
```

gatsby.browser.js

`require("prismjs/themes/prism-okaidia.css")`

And It is index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import Layout from "../layouts"
import Headline from '../components/headline'
import "../styles/main.scss"
import { redirectTo } from '@reach/router'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

class IndexPage extends Component {
  render() {
    const data = this.props.data.wordpressPage
    var codeTest = `
      var _self = (typeof window !== 'undefined')
    ? window   // if in browser
    : (
      (typeof WorkerGlobalScope !== 'undefined' && self instanceof WorkerGlobalScope)
      ? self // if in worker
      : {}   // if in node js
    );
    `
    var swift = `
      let test = "hellow"
      func test() -> Bool {
        return false
      }
    `
    return (
      <Layout>
      <Headline title={"I'm Shawn Baek"} subTitle={"iOS Developer"}/>
      <div
         style={{
           margin: '0 auto',
           maxWidth: 800,
           padding: '0px 1.0875rem 1.45rem',
           paddingTop: '1.45rem',
         }}
      >
      <div>
          <h1 style={{color:'rgb(76, 76, 76)'}}>{data.title}</h1>
          <div style={{color:'rgb(76, 76, 76)'}} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.content }}></div>
      </div>
      <pre className="javascript">
          <code >
              {codeTest}
          </code>
      </pre>
      <pre className="language-swift">
          <code >
              {swift}
          </code>
      </pre>
      </div>
    </Layout>
    )
  }
}

export const IndexPageQuery = graphql`
  query IndexPageQuery {
    wordpressPage(slug: { eq: "about" }) {
      title
      content
      date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
    }
  }
`
export default IndexPage
```

As you can see, PrismJS theme background color and font color is works. But syntax highlighting is not works like a token.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`gatsby-remark-whatever` plugins are specifically for use for Gatsby’s Remark Markdown parser, [`gatsby-transformer-remark`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-remark/).

When using Gatsby + WordPress however, your content is coming from WordPress, not Markdown files. That means your WordPress content isn’t modified by these plugins, and while you could potentially make this happen, it’s probably not the easiest way to solve the problem.

The same thing goes for your test: that string of sample code won’t go through Gatsby’s Markdown process, so the Markdown PrismJS plugin won’t have an impact.

If you use a WordPress plugin that adds the syntax highlights HTML you need server-side in PHP, this should be passed along through the WordPress REST API.

Then, you can manually add the CSS and theme customisations you want (kind of like how you might if you were building the front-end of a regular WordPress theme.)

Alternatively, you can use Prism.js as you might inside another React project. I think this [How to get PrismJS working in React](https://medium.com/get-it-working/get-prismjs-working-in-react-a6d989e59290) tutorial will help you most.

A similar example based on your code, after running `npm install prismjs`:

```js
// Import the PrismJS CSS, contained in the node_modules
// You might need to download a custom theme to support 
// some languages like Swift
import "prismjs/themes/prism.css";

import React, { Component } from "react";
import Prism from "prismjs";

class IndexPage extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    Prism.highlightAll();
  }

  render() {
    var sampleCode = `.example {
  font-weight: bold;
}`;

    return (
      <div>
        <pre>
          <code className="language-css">{sampleCode}</code>
        </pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default IndexPage;
```

If you aren’t using any other Markdown pages, you might decide to `npm uninstall` the `gatsby-remark-*` plugins and remove their config as well. Hope that’s helpful!